# IEnumerator casting? C#

Tags: c#

I am learning about IEnumerator and IEnumerable [new to c# in general].
I am trying to learn from this code example :

```
 class colors : IEnumerable , IEnumerator
{
    private string[] cols;
    private int iCurrent;

    public colors()
    {
        cols = new string[] { "Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow" };
        iCurrent = -1;

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }
}
```

there is more in the code but my question is about the last line.

Firstly I dont understand what will be returned and dont fully understand this line in the code. Would it be a colors IEnumerator type , would it be a string type . Where/on what ***this*** is pointing?

Secondly in CPP I remember I created iterators like , an example :

```
  std::map<object>::iterator it
```

,and then I would use it in a for[needed to add it.begin() , it.end()] loop . Now I understand that C# ,after I created this iterator/IEnumerator, has foreach loop that will spares me all this headace. But is there a way to create them easier/faster?

Comment: That example is incomplete.  It implements IEnumerable by returning an enumerator, but the class doesn't implement itself as an enumerator which would support being returned that way.  To do that it would need to define a property named Current, and methods MoveNext and Reset.  It would make a lot more sense for GetEnumerator to return cols.GetEnumerator, assuming the intent is to iterate that array.  But if the part you left out defines MoveNext and Reset and Current, then it makes perfect sense to return the object itself as an IEnumerator.

Comment: So anyway, the IEnumerator object being returned is of class colors.

Comment: @PaulKienitz you are right twice. 1st indeed I left part of the code out and that part does contain Current , MoveNext and Reset.2nd I tried return cols.GetEnumerator and it gives the same output

Comment: Its also a bit odd that this class is implementing the non-generic version of `IEnumerable`. That interface isn't used as often as `IEnumerable<T>` in modern code.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to create enumerators easier/faster?  Yes, with the `yield return` statement.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx  You declare one method returning an IEnumerable, and do all the iterating in there.  No need for MoveNext, Reset, or Current.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `IEnumerator` should likely be left to implementing your own custom containers (like if you were implementing hashset in C++). `IEnumerable`, which returns values of type `Object`, is implemented by containers and is sufficient to use `foreach`. `IEnumerable<string>` is the more strongly typed version and is likely what you'd want here.

An array of string, used in your example, allows you to enumerate its contents as `Strings`. Here are some examples using `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<string>` without implementing the enumerator yourself; perhaps they'll get you where you want to go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Colors : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    private readonly string[] cols = new[] { "Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow" };

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return cols.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Colors2
{
    private readonly string[] cols = new[] { "Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow" };

    public IEnumerable<string> Colors
    {
        get { return cols; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        Test2();
        Test3();
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        var colors = new Colors();
        foreach (var c in colors)
        {
            // c is of type Object here because it's IEnumerable.
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }

    private static void Test2()
    {
        var colors2 = new Colors2();
        foreach (var c in colors2.Colors)
        {
            // c is of type String here because it's IEnumerable<string>.
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }

    private static void Test3()
    {
        foreach (var c in new[] { "Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow" })
        {
            // c is of type String here.
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```